# SQL Inserting Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

Hey Guys I'm getting a syntax error with my `SQL` on my `PHP` page.

Basically what my page does is that it simply inserts data from a form and inserts into the database.

This is my code and my error:

```
Problem with query.
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', '', '', '', '', '')' at line 2

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, password, gname, mname, surname, address, state, postcode, tel)
VALUES ( '$usernamestr', '$passwordstr','$firstnamestr', '$middlenamestr’, '$familynamestr', '$addressstr', '$statestr', '$postcodestr', '$phonestr');";
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());
```

I thought this was the way to do it? which is absolutely weird.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/ -- Learn about [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and all your problems will be solved.

Comment: Clearly the variables don't have the expected values, which is great, because it's preventing passwords from being stored as plaintext.

Comment: Looks like the variables are empty.

Comment: Side note: You should escape the variables, before using them in the query.
http://de1.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string
or if you choose MYSQLi 
http://de1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a funky quote:

```
VALUES ( '$usernamestr', '$passwordstr','$firstnamestr', '$middlenamestr’, '$familynamestr', 
                                                                       ^^^^
                                                                       HERE
```

It is a `’` and needs to be a `'` (as the syntax highlighter shows in my answer but not in your question).

Comment: Thanks dude, I really cant believe i missed that. Looked exactly like a single quote to me.

Comment: I had to re-read it several times to spot it as it definitely does *not* stand out. If your query wasn't otherwise correct I wouldn't have looked at it quite so hard.